# Windows 7 NFS client slow

Tags: windows-7, nfs, centos6

I have a CentOS 6 VM running on a Windows 7 host.  I have NFS server running on the VM, and mounting it via windows' built-in NFS client on the windows host. However, it is incredibly slow. Namely, SVN checkouts to the share take upwards of 20 minutes, where checkouts to a local directory take about 55 seconds.  Any ideas why this would be so slow and/or how to improve it?

Comment: Why NFS, and not SMB?

Comment: UNIX permissions, symlinks, etc. in subversion are not preserved when using SMB, or VMware/VBox shared folders

Comment: OK, that makes sense. What about IO contention on the host?

Answer (score 1):

You have a Windows 7 (consumer OS, so this isn't the right site, but whatever) host. 
On the same machine, you have a CentOS VM.

You're using NFS to share files between them.

Is the guest VMDK on the same physical disk as either (or both) the Windows host OS or the NFS share? I'm thinking you're probably causing IO problems. Run Perfmon on the physical disk and see what results you get, maybe you need to move stuff around.

Or, you know, just use VMware Shared Folders to do this.